# Does qTip support the latest version of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, qtip

On the qTip site, the version of jQuery bundled with the qTip download is dated -- not the current stable 1.5.1 release of jQuery.

Does anyone know if qTip can work with 1.5.1 of jQuery? The qTip forums don't address compatibility issues.

If not qTip, which is a comparable tooltip plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it works out-of-the-box with jQuery 1.5, since it was written for 1.3.2 (which is ancient at this point), but it shouldn't be _too_ hard to patch qTip to work with jQuery 1.5.

Comment: thanks, matt. do you recommend another tooltip plugin instead?

Comment: Why do you not ask directly in their forum? There you should get a much better answer directly from the programmer.

Comment: the forums are not highly active, and i thought the SO community would provide a richer, speedier response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does still work with jQuery 1.5.1.  I threw together a simple demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/akHyX/

Comment: Check out the fiddle in IE7 your missing the corners.

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Qtip2 removed the corner builder in favor of corner-radius. there are solutions for adding corner-radius CSS support to IE6+, or alternatively you can go back to the original qtip.